# Filezilla won't transfer 10 files simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, sftp, filezilla

I can't recall when I noticed the problem/change but I used to be able to always transfer 10 files at the same time if I wanted but something has changed where it will never do that. Sometimes it is 6 or 7 but never 10.

I have done some looking around but everyone just says change the max downloads to 10 which it has always been.

[image: File Transfer Window]

[image: Transfer Settings Window]

If you need any additional information, please feel free to ask. I am transferring genomic data which would be nice to do in larger quantities rather than smaller.

tl;dr: is there anyway to make filezilla **always** transfer 10 files at once (for better or worse)? It currently does not do that although the setting is set for it.

Comment: May be a server setting controlling simultaneous uploads to you as well

Comment: you can try to open 2 instances

Comment: @panhandel - I tried a different source and I still get the same issue. Although - that doesn't rule out the possibility they are doing the same thing however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experince, every time I encountered this problem with any file transfer client (FileZilla, TotalCommander, DoubleCommander) it has always been the case of the server limiting connections. Most probably your server configuration changed.

Running multiple instances of your client connected to the same server won't help as the server limits the connections per ip or per account (you would either have to use a proxy and/or another user with the same priviledges on the remote system).

If it is the case of server limiting connections you will most likely see a notice in a log visible in the FileZilla main window (if you disabled it, it could be re-enabled via the view menu).

Answer (score -2):

First, what is the point of transferring multiple files at once?  It's not actually making things move any faster.  You're still limited by the max bandwidth - so in your scenario, you'll have 10 simultaneous slow connections instead of two fast connections.  There is no real speed improvement.  You're kind of stuck in the illusion of more control.

Secondly, the FTP server can limit the number of connections from your PC, and you can't control that no matter how you configure Filezilla.

Comment: How can you say that an asyncronous upload isn't faster then a syncronous upload?  If you are uploading multiple small files, and only a couple large files, the total time is decreased by not having to wait on the large files to upload.

Comment: It is not. Because no matter whether you are transmitting one file or 10 at the same time, the band width is always a hard limitation.

Comment: Having transfered transfered files from a VPS recently, and having the transfer(s) of all the files complete in a shorter amount of time, compared to transfering each file one at a time.  I respecfully disagree with your conclusion.